# The clearly wrong proof

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Bob claims to have a proof that $0.\dot1=1$.
That's $0.\overline1=1$, $0.(1)=1$ or $0.11111...=1$ in other common formats.
The proof starts $$\text{If }1x=0.\dot1,\\
\text{then }10x=1.\dot1\\
10x-1x=1.\dot1-0.\dot1\\1x=1\\
\text{substituting in the value of }1x\text{ for }0.\dot1\text{ (as defined at the start)}\\ 
\\0.\dot1=1$$

He is *not* wrong (Ignore the title). Everything is correct. Every number in this question is in base $10$.

How is this possible?

Comment: 10 minus 1 equals 1?????????

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> *"There are 10 types of people in this world, those who understand binary and those who don't."*
> Bob is doing his calculations in base 2 (aka. binary): $$0.111..._2 = 1_2$$ similarly to the the following in base 10: $$0.999..._{10} = 1_{10}$$ The apparently wrong part is correct when the calculation is done in base 2: $$10_2 - 1_2 = 1_2$$ The last sentence states that every number is in base 10, which interpreted correctly (as a binary number again) means that **every** number is in base $$10_2 = 2_{10}$$

Comment: Absolutely right! Well done.

Comment: if that were so then every number in every base would be in base 10 (ha ha) since that's how you write the base in the base.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, but the critical part works only for one base.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes. Actually I found that extra amusing and nice lateral thinking ("base ten" in numbers).

Comment: [Every base is base 10](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?p=2398222#p2398222).  (And the jokes on that link are a lot of fun :)

Comment: What is the base of the base annotation?

Comment: @Kroltan 10 of course. ;)

Comment: @Sleafar 16? That's what I thought.

Comment: @Kroltan Nope, they are [plain and simple decimal numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Base.html). Otherwise I would need base annotations for base annotations ...

Comment: @Sleafar That's the joke: recursive base annotating.

Comment: Damn! I thought the answer was beyond the binary base. I took the usage of binary base as starting point... and perhaps answer why periodic 0.111... = 1.

Comment: Base 9+1 is surprisingly unambiguous however, (i think).

Answer (score 8):

Well:

> $10x−1x=1.\dot1−0.\dot1$
>  $1x=1$

Is wrong. It should be:

> $10x−1x=1.\dot1−0.\dot1$
>  $9x=1$

Then everything works out correctly.

Comment: No, it's not wrong. Bob is doing something different. You have to read the question more deeply to find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Bob's system of math, the symbol '-' does not mean subtract; instead, it means divide, then take the base 10 log.

Therefore, 10x - 1x = (10-1) * x = log(10/1) * x = 1x   (LHS) and
1.111... - .111... = log(10/9 * 9/1) = 1    (RHS)

Since step 3 to step 4 is the only "error" in the proof, the proof is now correct.

Comment: Wouldn't it be (For the left) $10x-1x=\log_{10}(\frac{10x}{1x})=\log_{10}(10)=1$, and not $1x$? $10x-1x\neq (10-1)\times x$ with this meaning of subtract.