# Correct way to add 22 to 4 to get 82

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

Inspired by [this other puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-given-value), tell me a correct way by which adding 22 to 4 will give 82.

As in that other puzzle, these numbers are all expressed in base 10.

Comment: (I almost posted this little tidbit as a comment on the other puzzle, before deciding that it might be interesting enough to stand on its own.)

Comment: Looks like you already get 3 correct answer and didnt match your desire solution. Maybe you should add more info.

Comment: You say "As in that other puzzle, these numbers are all expressed in base 10." But that's not quite true based on the answer you selected in the other puzzle.

Comment: @gtwebb there's a difference between *base* and *modulo*. Those are still *base-10* because 10 = 9+1. If it were *base-8* (for example) then 10 = 7+1. In *base-12* 10 = 9+3. A 24-hour clock is *modulo-24*, meaning 23+1 = 0, but it is still *base-10*. Similarly month numbers are *modulo-12* but again still *base-10*.

Comment: Nice question with three excellent answers - does it make that *too broad* and VTC? (Just joking. But I think you might want to accept one answer and/or add your answer as intendet as well.)

Comment: I am completely baffled about the answers. Ths site is just great.

Comment: You should change "expressed in base 10" to "expressed in decimal". All integers n are "10", when expressed in base n.

Comment: so many completely different answers.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

In French:

> Quatre (4) can be added to vingt deux (22) to make "Quatre-vingts deux" (82)

Comment: Brilliant! It is also valid answer to question "Can you subtract 22 from 4 and get 82?" (note the dash) :-D

Comment: I feel like this one is probably the correct one.

Comment: *“Vingt”* only takes an *s* at the end of *“quatre-vingts”* when it is not followed by anything else. Here, you should write *“quatre-vingt-deux”* (and *“vingt-deux”*, actually, with a dash as well).

Comment: This one was, indeed, my intended answer!  Been amazed at how many other great answers there have been, though!  :)

Comment: Merci Édouard. Je suis en train de apprendre français mais je ne suis pas couramment.

Comment: This is not base 10.

Comment: Taemyr, the question might have been wordplay, but the numbers are most definitely base 10.

Comment: Now it has 82 upvotes! :P

Comment: @JATerroba 'Quatre-vingts' is clearly base twenty.

Comment: No the french have words for 10-60 so for 70 they use 60+10, 80 4*20, and 90 80+10

Comment: Note that there is a common pronunciation quirk that makes this solution uneven. In "vingt-deux', the French often pronounce the middle "t" whereas in "quatre-vingt-deux" it is always silent. Pronouncing "vingt-deux" like "quatre-vingt-deux" to mean 22 sounds awkward.

Comment: @ev3commander: Specific words exist for 70, 80 and 90, from old French, in Switzerland and Belgium.

Comment: Ok, but I'm talking about French in France

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Only 70 and 90 borrow from old French in Belgium: 80 is pronounced "quatre-vingts" as it is in France.

Comment: As a French speaker, the "in French" part should've been in a spoiler tag as well. The answer was immediately obvious to me after "accidentally" peeking in the answer section (but not the spoiler). 

Answer (score 235):

> If you superimpose a seven-segment display $4$ onto the first $2$, it becomes an $8$:
>  [image: LED digits superimposed]

So we have the 'sum':

$$22+$$
$$4\;=$$
$$82\;\;\;$$

Comment: this could just as easily give 28 instead of course. also you'd get the same answer adding 5, 6, 8, 9 or even 0!

Answer (score 161):

My suggestion:

> 1. Form with matchsticks roman representation of 22 - **XXII**
>   2. Add 4 matchsticks in front forming **LX**
>   3. The result is **LXXXII**, which is 82

Comment: Also not even remotely like my intended answer, but this one is awesome, too, and probably satisfies the terms of the puzzle as I phrased it!  But the answer I'm really looking for involves actually adding the number 22 to the number 4, not to 4 matchsticks which are cleverly arranged to represent the number 60.  :)

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff +1 for making pun of a box of matches. Take note of the difference between "out of the box" (=standard solution) and "outside the box" (=original solution), though.

Answer (score 104):

> 4 groats +
>  22 threepenny bits =
>  82 pence (in old money, UK).

And thank goodness we don't use those any more.

Comment: You win one guinea's worth of internet.

Answer (score 35):

Make the text Upside down / Or rotate text to 180 degree:

> [image]

So the upside down text reads:

**Twenty Eight** equals **Six** plus **Twenty Two**

Answer (score 22):

My guess:

> 22 weeks + 4 Semesters (15 weeks in each semester) = 82 weeks

Comment: where I am from, a such a thing lasts 6 months.

Comment: Semester mean six months, isnt? so at least 24 weeks? But better aproach is half year or 26 weeks.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The name "Semester", linguistically, should be six months, but generally it means "half of an academic year" - and in the US, there's normally a "summer break" (or "summer semester" if you're taking classes).

Comment: Similar and not so ambiguous could be present with minutes and quarters ;)

Comment: but still, 10/2=5 months. 5 months*>4 wks/month = >20 wks =/= 15 wks

Answer (score 20):

In the set of integers modulo 14 $(\mathbb Z_{14})$:

> $\overline{22} + \overline 4 = \overline {14+8} + \overline 4 = \overline {8} + \overline 4 = \overline {12} = \overline {12} + \overline{5\times 14} = \overline {12+5\times 14}=\overline {82}$

Alternatively, use the integers modulo 56:

> $\overline{22}+\overline{4 }=\overline{22+4}=\overline{26}= \overline{56+26}=\overline{82}$

where $\overline x$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$.

Comment: Soon someone will complain that you are using another base than 10...

Comment: @Olba12 Let them display their ignorance.

Comment: Of course, in $\mathbb{Z}$ the difference between $82$ and $22+4$ is $56$, so if you pick any divisor $d$ of $56$, then this will work modulo $d$ (i.e. in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$), and it will work with no other modulus. The positive divisors of $56$ are: $1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 14, 28, 56$.

Answer (score 20):

by ear:

> *"tell me a correct way by which adding two two to four will give 82."* 
>  is the same as
> *"tell me a correct way by which adding 2224 will give 82."*

And so the answer is

> -2142

Or written longly

> The way by which adding 2224 will give 82, is by adding it to -2142.

Answer (score 8):

Since there's an accepted answer, I'm not going to bother hiding...

$(2_{10} 2_{10})_{38} + (4_{10})_{38} = 26_{38} = 76_{10} + 6_{10} = 82_{10}$

where subscripts indicate the base in which the number is written.

EDIT:  Comments indicate this is not a new idea.  (Every number in base $b$ is in base $10_b$.)

Comment: "these numbers are all expressed in base 10."

Comment: @f'' : Apparently my fingers are smarter about the idea I was trying to capture than my perverse brain is, and filtered out the intended content.  Bad fingers.  Bad.

Comment: @f'' : [Base 10 is not a limitation](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29246/the-clearly-wrong-proof).

Comment: @aluriak That one is [tag:lateral-thinking], this one isn't.

Comment: @f'' : Not sure that a base-implicit number belongs to lateral-thinking.

Answer (score 7):

Since several answers are making use of modulo arithmetic (and I know they were not the selected answers), I'm just going to throw this stupid solution out there.

$[22]_1$ + $[4]_1$ = $[82]_1$

Comment: Haha! Ofc the most obvious one. I choosed $[.]_4$ becuase then I could relate to winter, spring, summer autumn... heh

Answer (score 6):

> We have summer, autumn, winter and spring. If we say that summer is $0$ then autumn is $1$, winter $2$, and spring $3$. Then $4 + 22 = 26$ which is $6$ cycles of summer->autumn->winter->spring then followed by autumn->winter. Which of course is equal to $20$ cycles of summer->autumn->winter->spring followed by autumn->winter. That is why $22+4=82,$ because winter is coming.

or explained with math

> $[22]_4 + [4]_4 = [26]_4 = [2]_4 = [80+2]_4 = [82]_4$ using that $[a]_4 = \{ b \ | \ b \equiv a \pmod{4} \}$ since we have that $ b \equiv a \pmod{n} $ iff $ [a]_n = [b]_n$ it follows directly that since $82 \equiv 26 \pmod{4}$ then $[82]_4 = [26]_4$ and by using the arithmetic rules of congruence classes modulo $n$. We get have that $[82]_4 = [26]_4 = [22 + 4]_4 = [22]_4 + [4]_4$

Comment: Is this a joke?  It doesn't make sense to me; please expand on the explanation. And add spoiler markdown.

Comment: @PeregrineRook , I guess , answer refers to base 4 (the 4 Digits are 0=summer , 1=autumn , 2=winter & 3=spring) , where 22+4=26=2 (base 4) & 82=2 (base 4) , and "2=winter" , so answer says "22+4=82 , because winter is coming" , but question specifically says that the given numbers are base 10 , so **this answer is invalid**.

Comment: No, im using base 10, with modulo arithmetic. @Prem

Comment: I have added a spoiler and updated my explanationen @PeregrineRook

Comment: @Olba12 , I must have been sleepy when I commented earlier. When I said "base 4" , I meant "mod 4". After further confusion between base and mod, I came to wrong conclusion about the validity of your answer. I will delete my comments after some time.

Comment: How can 26 in base 4 is equal to 2 base 4?

Comment: THIS IS NOT BASE 4?!

Comment: An 8 and a 6 are digits that do not exist in base 4. Thus, this is not base 4. It is the integers modulo 4.