# Correct way to add 22 to 4 to get 70

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

Based on the other "[Correct way to add 22 to 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-82)" puzzles.

Tell me the correct way to add 22 to 4 to get 70
As in the other puzzles, all numbers are in Base 10.

Comment: I think this question requires a little bit more effort - perhaps a link to the original puzzle? Also the question itself should be in the body, not just the title.

Comment: I think it's fine as it is

Comment: @CallumBradbury check the revision history - it's much better now, I reckon.

Comment: Do we have to think in other language than English to get the answer, just like the other question. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/33263/19658

Comment: I would add them all and reduce by 26.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible answer:

> 4 feet + 22 yards (66 feet) = 70 feet

Comment: This was the intended answer.

Answer (score 9):

I did so many calculations on the other puzzle that this one is easy from memory :)

> 4 years + 22 months = 70 months

Comment: Nice.  Looking at the other questions, this answer is far better than mine. +1

Answer (score 4):

Not really adding but...

> 4/22 (April 22) is Earth Day

and

> The first Earth Day was in 1970

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer:

> 4 dozen + 22 = 70

or

> (4*12=48)+22=70

Answer (score 2):

In the additive cyclic group of integers modulo $44$ $(\mathbb Z_{44})$:

> $\overline{22}+\overline{4 }=\overline{22+4}=\overline{26}= \overline{44+26}=\overline{70}$, where $\overline x$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer:

> The questions asks how to add 22 *to* 4 to get 70: Add twenty-two 3s to 4:
> $22\times 3 + 4 = 70$

Answer (score -3):

it will be

> 4 dozens (12 * 4 )+ 22 =70