# Correct way to add 22 to 4 to get two different results

Tags: logical-deduction

Inspired [by these series of puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-82), tell me a correct way by which adding 22 to 4 will give either 495 or 505.

As in the other puzzles, these numbers are all expressed in base 10.

Comment: Come on, another one? These are getting stale

Comment: @KoA yeah too boring isn't it escpecially with the fan followings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you get these answers by

> Converting each of the numbers to a letter of the alphabet with the convention 1=A, 2=B, etc, so that 4=D and 22=V. 
>  Then, concatenate the letters so that you obtain either **DV** or **VD** and interpret the result as a Roman numeral so 
>  **DV**=505 and **VD** could perhaps be interpreted as 495.

Comment: But... 495 is CDXCV !

Comment: Yes, we're using our Roman numerals very liberally here.