# Almost half a million, yet smaller than a hundred

Tags: lateral-thinking

Consider, for example, the number 420109. It's quite big, isn't it? Not so far from half a million. Yet it can be interpreted to be smaller than a hundred with a very simple trick, without putting any mathematical operators between the digits, without using any mathematical function on it, and without erasing or hiding parts of it.

**How?**

---

Hint 1

> There are a few other 6-digit numbers this could work with, but not many.

Hint 2

> Not only can it "be made smaller", 420109 actually *is* smaller than 100 from a certain viewpoint. There are very few 6-digit numbers where this can be applied.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous formulation. I meant 100 as a number. The "a" in "a hundred" was superfluous. I corrected it now.

Comment: So it can be made smaller than 100?

Comment: rot13(Vf vg eryngrq gb n qngr, r.t. ner gur 4 zvqqyr qvtvgf "2010")?

Comment: @Earlien no, its nothing in that direction

Comment: I thought I've seen here [something similar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-82) before.

Comment: In my opinion hint 1 shouldn't be a hint, it restricts the possible solutions (see @CG. answer; it works but not with the hints) so it should be part of the main riddle

Comment: @Gilsido isn't the whole point of a hint to restrict the possible solutions?

Comment: @JakeRobb I'm sure that the point of a hint is not restricting the possible solutions, but to restrict our focus to get the solution. A puzzle with many possible solutions are highly discouraged (and may be closed as "too broad".) A puzzle should have a single correct solution, and hints are given to make us easier getting that correct solution.

Comment: Based on the title, I wanted the answer to be "milli-" as a prefix meaning 1/1000, but also about half of the word "million" :(

Comment: Edit: Changed the wording to be less ambiguous, as that word seemed to be the most likely cause why people voted to close.

Comment: I like the edit, it makes the puzzle way more approachable. Voting to reopen, again.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Pardon my French, but no whole number smaller than 100 can be larger than 99, so this puzzle must be completely and utterly

> brilliant, because 99 is "quatre-vingt-dix-neuf" or "four-twenty-ten-nine" in French.

Comment: This one has to be right! Great thinking

Comment: A puzzle, created only for those who speak French. Sadly, I'm not among them.

Comment: Rot13(Ba orunys bs gur Serapu crbcyr, V jbhyq yvxr gb ncbybtvfr gb nyy gubfr jub unq gb yrnea gb pbhag gb n uhaqerq va bhe ynathntr...)

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: @AleksandrH - Rot13(Ybbx hc gur Serapu ahzorevat ehyrf. Hayvxr va Ratyvfu, jurer lbh fnl "avargl" gura "avar" sbe avargl-avar, va Serapu gurl fnl "sbhe gjraglf, n gra, naq n avar" gb trg avargl-avar. ...urapr eru-cs' pbzzrag.)

Comment: The only reason why I get this one is because of _Diebuster_ and its [Buster Machine](https://gunbuster.fandom.com/wiki/Buster_Machines) nomenclature.

Comment: @eru-cs, Vg'f abg ernyyl gung onq. Hc gb 69, vg'f gur fnzr va Serapu va Ratyvfu. Gur bayl jrveqarff vf gung 70-79 vf 6-10..6..19 vafgrnq bs 7,7-1..7-9. Fnzr sbe gur 90'f. Bar fvzcyr yvggyr qvssrerapr sebz Ratyvfu.

Answer (score 35):

Lateral thinking here:

> The 010 part of the number looks like a % symbol, so the number could be viewed as 42 % 9 which is less than 100.

Comment: Wow! Just wow! I never thought of that. It violates some of the hints (it would be a mathematical operator), but still, you get the +1 for the idea.

Comment: JS1 isn't "putting" operators anywhere; JS1 is misinterpreting something already there as an operator.

Comment: That operation will only be recognized to programmers who work in a C-based language.  To most other people (including mathematicians), it'll be gibberish.

Comment: % is used in a lot of other programming languages as well, but your point remains valid.

Comment: As someone that knows C but not French, I'm upvoting this one.

Comment: @BlueRaja-Danny: I think most others would interpret it as 42% of 9, which still works.

Answer (score 34):

Well, seeing that this is lateral thinking:

> You wrote 420109 using 6 digits, and a hundred using 7 letters. So, it's smaller.

Comment: nice thinking, but I didn't say shorter, but smaller.

Comment: I would claim smaller = shorter for a word, but ok. :-)

Answer (score 26):

Following up on @Earlien answer I think the trick is to

> decompose 420109 as 4 20 10 9 and read it in French

This gives

> 99 = 4*20 + 10 + 9 which is one unit less than 100

Similarly

> 420108 would read as 98

Comment: This is definitely the right answer.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's definitely how they read it, no trick involved :)

Comment: Oh, I sniped you by just over 2 minutes? Good thing I didn't notice the question was 7 hours old when I hurried to answer, then. :-) As per tradition, +1 to you too.

Answer (score 15):

Is it the way it’s read?

> Four “20’s” and 1 “09” = 89

Comment: This *has* to be it.

Comment: If it is, Hint 1 seems misleading.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. There are 900,000 6-digit numbers, and this will work for maybe 0.1% of them.

Comment: At least it's closer than all the other answers. The real answer is much more self-evident, however, it might require some knowledge not all of us have.

Comment: @vsz In that case, does the question perhaps require the [tag:knowledge] tag?

Comment: Whoever likes this answer will probably also enjoy my mathematical posts on "self-describing" numbers, which use a very similar principle: https://projectatmos.space/profile/1p8WCZnqqG6N3ZOsJxBgUTo/p1cNCw1OTsioTQBRk

Answer (score 10):

This is a really silly idea, but:

> Put a minus sign before it to make it -420109. It's smaller than 100, and technically speaking, I haven't put a mathematical operator *between* the digits.

It obviously doesn't fit the first hint, but it adheres to the wording of the actual puzzle.

Comment: Nice idea but by that logic all of the positive numbers (six digit or otherwise) could be made smaller than 100.

Answer (score 9):

Well... there's always...

> 100
>  <sub><sup><sub><sup>420109</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Doesn't seem to mesh with the idea that there are very few of these 6-digit numbers that work, though.

Answer (score 8):

Although I really like Bass' idea, I want to offer another, rule-bending, idea:

> Put in a decimal point (or a comma, depending where you live) and make it **4.20109**

Now the number is definitely below 100 without breaking the rules:

> - Putting in a single pixel is as easy as it gets (and we don't need to learn another language!)
>  - Not a mathematical function
>  - No hiding or erasing of numbers
>  - Not a mathematical operator (although a mathematical symbol)

Comment: Nice thinking, but it wouldn't satisfy Hint 1.

Comment: True, I did not take the hints into account.

Answer (score 7):

Two possible solutions:

> - It is smaller than a hundred, if you write "a hundred" very large.
>  - It is smaller than a hundred *of itself* (or of some other unspecified quantity).

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is

> 49

Because

> The first thing I saw was how the shapes of the letters match up. By transposing the 2 on the top of the 4, it becomes a funky looking 4, but still a 4. Then place the 1 on it as well. Still a 4. Then the 0's can be slightly shrunk and placed on top part of the nine.
> I hope I'm at least on the right track. Otherwise, I'm crazier than I thought. 
> Sorry, in a rush. I was the best picture I could do:) 
>  [image]

Answer (score 6):

<sub>420109</sub>

```
 1       00      00
 1      0  0    0  0
 1      0  0    0  0
 1       00      00
```

Comment: This has ended up in the "low quality" queue, but it seems like an okay answer to me as it's using a literal definition of "smaller".

Answer (score 5):

No trick involved, because

> it is almost half a million but certainly a lot smaller than hundred (millions).

Answer (score 4):

420109 is 19

> in base 420100

or

> in the list of multiples of 22111... I was hoping this was a Prime thing....

Answer (score 3):

This is the stupidest solution I've ever cooked up, but here it is anyway.

> Turn the 1 sideways to make it a divisor for a fraction. Now you get 420/09, which comes out to be way less than 100. This is, of course, monumentally stupid and I hate it. If it's the right answer, I will be sad.